# Why is my MaskedEditValidator is not working?

Tags: asp.net, maskededitextender, comparevalidator

I have following controls in my page, my CompareValidator works, but not the MaskedEditValidator. Am I missing anything?

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <div>
        Date: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="TextBox1_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
            Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TextBox1">
        </asp:CalendarExtender>
        <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="TextBox1_MaskedEditExtender" runat="server" 
            CultureAMPMPlaceholder="" CultureCurrencySymbolPlaceholder="" 
            CultureDateFormat="" CultureDatePlaceholder="" CultureDecimalPlaceholder="" 
            CultureThousandsPlaceholder="" CultureTimePlaceholder="" Enabled="True" 
            TargetControlID="TextBox1" Mask="99/99/9999" MaskType="Date">
        </asp:MaskedEditExtender>
        <%--<asp:MaskedEditValidator ID="MaskedEditValidator1" runat="server" 
            ControlExtender="TextBox1_MaskedEditExtender" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" 
            ErrorMessage="The Date is not valid!" IsValidEmpty="False">
        </asp:MaskedEditValidator>--%>        
        <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage="Invalid Date!" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" 
            Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Date">
        </asp:CompareValidator>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="PostBack" 
            onclick="Button1_Click" style="height: 26px; width: 85px" />
        <br /><br />
        Selected Date:<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: I copied the page above and the MaskedEditExtender works fine. Do you mean the MaskedEditValidator?

Comment: Yeh. I mean the MaskedEditValidator. If you uncomment it, and comment the CompareValidator, and input an invalid date, the error message "The Date is not valid" will not show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your MaskedEditValidator with the following:

```
<asp:MaskedEditValidator ID="MaskedEditValidator1"  runat="server"
ControlExtender="TextBox1_MaskedEditExtender" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
IsValidEmpty="False" EmptyValueMessage="Invalid Date" 
InvalidValueMessage="The Date is not valid!"> 
</asp:MaskedEditValidator>
```

The key thing is that you needed InvalidValueMessage and/or EmptyValueMessage instead of ErrorText.